# Arduino how can run the relay module?

Tags: arduino, relay

Relay modules have 3 pins + and - and input signal, input signal must be negative to runing the relay, so if output pins of arduino are +, how can run the relay?
output voltage of arduino pins can some time become negative or always positive?[image: Relay input signal]?

Comment: Errm, your signal isn't negative, its zero. But I don't get what you mean - presumably if you apply a high it will turn the relay off, if you apply a low it will turn the relay on. An Arduino is perfectly capable of driving both a high and a low, so what's the issue?

Comment: Is that a photo of your relay? Because if it is then you have a 12V version, so it really needs 12V to operate correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your relay apparently operates when the input is connected to ground, not when it is taken to some negative voltage, so the relay should operate when the Arduino outputs a logic Low or 0 (voltage near ground), and will release when the Arduino outputs a logic High or 1 (voltage near Vcc).

Answer (score 1):

The relay is dual throw. A high signal on the input will connect common with one of the output terminals, and a low will connect it with the other output terminal. That's why there are three terminals on the left. Try connecting your load to the other output terminal and see if that changes the behavior. I've seen this relay uses on a zillion Arduino accessories so I assume it switches with 5V.